# Link issues with QtMacExtras using Qt 5.0.2

Tags: macos, qt, linker

I need the [QtMacExtras](http://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qtmacextras) framework to use its QMacCocoaViewContainer class.

I have been able to get the framework and compile it easily using qmake/make without issues.
However, when trying to link my binary with it I get undefined symbols errors.
The compilation of the objects works like a charm.

```
g++ -mmacosx-version-min=10.7 --exported_symbols_list=symbols.exp -Wl,-x -L/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/usr/lib -o myBinary *.o -bind_at_load -F/pathToMy/Frameworks -framework QtCore -framework QtMacExtras -framework QtGui -framework QtWidgets #...
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "QMacCocoaViewContainer::QMacCocoaViewContainer(objc_object*, QWidget*)", referenced from:
    WbDockWidget::setContentWindowId(unsigned long long)in WbDockWidget.o
  ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

The code to instantiate the class is the following:

```
#include <QtMacExtras/QMacCocoaViewContainer>
// ...
NSView *view = reinterpret_cast<NSView *>(id);
QWidget *widget = new QMacCocoaViewContainer(view, this);
```

Commenting this code allows to compile my project.

The framework seems correctly linked, seems to include correctly the headers, and seems to contain the symbols (!):

```
$ nm -g Frameworks/QtMacExtras.framework/Versions/5/QtMacExtras | grep -i cocoa
0000000000009240 T __ZN22QMacCocoaViewContainer11qt_metacallEN11QMetaObject4CallEiPPv
0000000000009200 T __ZN22QMacCocoaViewContainer11qt_metacastEPKc
0000000000004c00 T __ZN22QMacCocoaViewContainer12setCocoaViewEP6NSView
0000000000011130 S __ZN22QMacCocoaViewContainer16staticMetaObjectE
0000000000004b60 T __ZN22QMacCocoaViewContainerC1EP6NSViewP7QWidget
0000000000004b70 T __ZN22QMacCocoaViewContainerC2EP6NSViewP7QWidget
0000000000004d10 T __ZN22QMacCocoaViewContainerD0Ev
0000000000004d40 T __ZN22QMacCocoaViewContainerD1Ev
0000000000004d90 T __ZN22QMacCocoaViewContainerD2Ev
00000000000091e0 T __ZNK22QMacCocoaViewContainer10metaObjectEv
0000000000004e20 T __ZNK22QMacCocoaViewContainer9cocoaViewEv
0000000000011360 S __ZTI22QMacCocoaViewContainer
000000000000ce70 S __ZTS22QMacCocoaViewContainer
0000000000011160 S __ZTV22QMacCocoaViewContainer
0000000000004d50 T __ZThn16_N22QMacCocoaViewContainerD0Ev
0000000000004e10 T __ZThn16_N22QMacCocoaViewContainerD1Ev
```

Any suggestion to be able to use this class would be more than welcome.

Sincerely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs when you build as C++.

The easiest way to fix this is to switch the extension to `.mm`, but if you force the toolchain to build as Objective C++ by whatever means it should fix the issue.

Comment: This issue report is old, I have issues to test it. Your solution makes a lot of sense, so I will accept it as the answer.